# Windows Firewall Exception for Youtube API v3.0

Tags: youtube-api, windows-firewall

I am working on a wp plugin that previously utilized YouTube API v2.0 to implement v3.0. On my development server everything is working as expected. However, on the live server calls to the API are not showing up in the API traffic.

Is there a specific exception I can add to the Windows Firewall so that the live server can access the YouTube v3.0 API?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  Is your fire wall blocking it ?

Comment: Check your API key credentials for any restrictions by IP or referrer.